# Rails + foundation : load order and adding custom javascript to foundation elements

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

A preamble: this is not another turbolinks issue :) I have actually removed turbolinks from my Gemfile and my application.js.

So I'm running a Rails 4.2.0 application. I'm using the foundation-rails gem and jquery-rails.
As advised, I initialize the foundation niceties in the **application.js**

```javascript
$(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

In my controller javascript (coffeescript actually), I have the following binding to foundation reveal events (to have custom behavior on my modal)

```coffee
$( () ->
    bindReveal()        
)

bindReveal = () ->
    $(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '#modal-thanks', (event) ->
        if 'fndtn.reveal' == event.namespace
            modal = $(this)
            modalTimeout = window.setTimeout( () ->
                modal.foundation('reveal', 'close')
            , 1500)
    )

    $(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '#modal-thanks', (event) ->
        if 'fndtn.reveal' == event.namespace
            window.clearTimeout(modalTimeout)
            modalTimeout = 0
            goToNextQuestion()
    )
```

If I do that, actually it does not work. The modal does appear but the events are not bound.

I actually tracked it down to the fact that through the sprockets instruction

```
//= require_tree .
```

in the application.js, the controller js code actually is executed BEFORE the application.js body code, that contains the foundation init call. So when I try to bind my foundation events, foundation is actually not started.

I have a solution, see below, but it does not 100% satisfy me.

So my question: Am I missing something? What are the best practices working with foundation-rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to emit my own custom event once the foundation is initialized and to bind my events there

applications.js:

```
//= require_tree .

$(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
  $(document).trigger("done.speedyrating.foundation");
});
```

controller.coffeescript:

```
$( () ->
    setupPostFoundation()        
)

setupPostFoundation = () ->
    $(document).on("done.speedyrating.foundation", () ->
        setupDropdownMenu()
        setupModalThanks()
    )
```

While this works just nicely, I feel like I must be missing something there. It's not possible that there is a "hole" like this and that it's not documented. Many people must encounter the same issue, though my research didn't bring me anywhere.